# Plot line that changes color based on values in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is my table:

```
date        CumRet1     CumRet2     Boom
1973-01-31  1.112309    1.011383    True
1973-02-28  1.120466    1.021701    True
1973-03-31  1.125156    1.030822    True
1973-04-30  1.135342    1.067682    True
1973-05-31  1.136887    1.069136    False
1973-06-30  1.139889    1.071959    False
```

I want to plot a line, that colors Cumulative Return1 in black and Cumulative Return2 in blue if Boom is True and in red if Boom is false. Unfortunately, my code produces three lines in my graph, where the second cumulative return is grouped into True or False. Can anyone help me with that issue?

This is my approach:

```
ggplot() +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x = date, y = CumRet2, color = BOOM), size=1) +
  geom_line(data = df, aes(x = date, y = CumRet1), size=1)
```

Comment: Could you be clearer about what your expected graph will look like? Ideally with a sketch. Are you expecting two lines one each for CumRet1 and one for CumRet2. Are you expecting a multi coloured line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my best guess at understanding your question.

#### data

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

df <- structure(list(date = c("1973-01-31", "1973-02-28", "1973-03-31", 
                              "1973-04-30", "1973-05-31", "1973-06-30"),
                     CumRet1 = c(1.112309, 1.120466, 1.125156, 1.135342, 1.136887, 1.139889), 
                     CumRet2 = c(1.011383, 1.021701, 1.030822, 1.067682, 1.069136, 1.071959),
                     Boom = c("True", "True", "True", "True", "False", "False")), 
                class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

#### wrangle

to get data in "long" format and create a grouping for the three cases which are to be mapped to different colours.

```
  df <- 
    df %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = starts_with("Cum"), names_to = "var", values_to = "val") %>% 
    mutate(g = case_when(var =="CumRet1" & Boom == "True" ~ "g1",
                         var =="CumRet2" & Boom == "True" ~ "g2",
                         TRUE ~ "g3"))
```

#### plot

```
ggplot(df, aes(date, y = val)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = g, group = var), size = 1)+
  scale_colour_manual(breaks = c("g1", "g2", "g3"), 
                      values = c("black", "blue", "red"),
                      labels = c("Cumulative return 1, Boom; True", 
                                 "Cumulative return 2, Boom; True",
                                 "Cumulative return 1 or 2, Boom; False"))+
  labs(colour = "Cumulative return")+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")+
  guides(colour=guide_legend(ncol = 2, byrow=TRUE))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-05-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>